# Django - get latest object in each relation

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Let's assume I have a `Product` model in my project:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

and I want to have some sort of statistics (let's say I want to keep track of how has the price changed over time) for it:

```
class ProductStatistics(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
    statistics_value = models.IntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

    @classmethod
    def create_for_product(cls, product_ids):
        statistics = []
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=products_ids)
        for product in products:
            statistics.append(
                product=product
                statistics_value=product.price
            )
        cls.objects.bulk_create(statistics)

    @classmethod
    def get_latest_by_products_ids(cls, product_ids):
        return None
```

I have a problem with implementing `get_latest_by_products_ids` method. I want only latest statistic, so I can't do something like:

```
    @classmethod
    def get_latest_by_products_ids(cls, product_ids):
        return cls.objects.filter(product__id__in=product_ids)
```

because this would return all statistics I have gathered through time. How can I limit the query to only most recent one for each Product?

**EDIT**
I am using PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 1):

[Querysets already have a `last()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#last) (and a `first()` method too FWIW). The only question is what you want to define as "last" since this depends on the queryset's ordering... But assuming you want the last by creation date (`created` field), you can also [use the `lastest()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#latest):

```
@classmethod
def get_latest_by_products_ids(cls, product_ids):
    found = []
    for pid in products_ids:
        found.append(cls.objects.filter(product_id=pid).latest("created"))
    return found
```

As a side note: [Django's coding style is to use the `Manager` (and eventually the `Queryset`) for operations working on the whole table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods), so instead of creating classmethods on your model you should create a custom manager:

```
class productStatisticManager(models.Manager):

    def create_for_products(self, product_ids):
        statistics = []
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=products_ids)
        for product in products:
            statistics.append(
                product=product
                statistics_value=product.price
            )
        self.bulk_create(statistics)

    def get_latest_by_products_ids(cls, product_ids):
        found = []
        for pid in products_ids:
           last = self.objects.filter(product_id=pid).latest("created")         
           found.append(last)
        return found

class ProductStatistics(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
    statistics_value = models.IntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

    objects = ProductStatisticManager()
```

Comment: Is it possible to fetch this data in a single query instead of performing them in each loop iteration?

Comment: @gonczor can you write the SQL query that would do this in a single pass ?

Comment: I am looking through docs and it seems that django can perform something like `DISTINCT ON column_name` with PostgreSQL databases (sorry, I haven't mentioned I'm working with it earlier). It seems that this query: `self.filter(product__pk__in=product_ids).order_by('product', '-created',).distinct( 'product',)` does the job, but I still need to test it. Anyway, +1 for style suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the method in Product model and will be easier:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def get_latest_stat(self):
        return self.productstatistics_set.all().order_by('-created')[0] # or [:1]
```

Using [:1] instead of [0] will return QuerySet of single element while [0] will return just one Object of model Class.

eg.

```
>>> type(cls.objects.filter(product__id__in=product_ids).order_by('-created')[:1])
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
>>> type(cls.objects.filter(product__id__in=product_ids).order_by('-created')[0])
<class 'myApp.models.MyModel'>
```

Comment: The problem is I want one `ProductStatistics` object for each `Product` id of which I pass.